# How to use arrayUnion with AngularFirestore?

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have a basic database that essentially stores an array of product id's underneath a user. The user can select products to add to the array so it makes sense to use 'arrayUnion' so I avoid reading and re-writing the array constantly, however, I keep getting the error *"Property 'firestore' does not exist on type 'FirebaseNamespace'."

I've followed the documentation found at: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#update_elements_in_an_array but I fear I'm still using it incorrectly.

My code for updating the array is:

```
 addToPad(notepadName: string){
    const updateRef = this.db.collection('users').doc(this.activeUserID).collection('notepads').doc(notepadName);
    updateRef.update({
      products: firebase.firestore.FieldValue.arrayUnion(this.productId)
    });
  }
```

Comment: Are u using angularfire?

Comment: @PeterHaddad yes, though I can't find any documentation on the correct usage of arrayUnion with angularfire, so could only go off the standard firebase documentation

Answer (score 10, accepted):

First you need to import `firestore`:

```
import { firestore } from 'firebase/app';
```

Then you will be able to use `arrayUnion`:

```
addToPad(notepadName: string){
    const updateRef = this.db.collection('users').doc(this.activeUserID).collection('notepads').doc(notepadName);
    updateRef.update({
      products: firestore.FieldValue.arrayUnion(this.productId)
    });
  }
```

Comment: Ah - perfect! I was using '@firebase/app' previously so this was the issue.

Comment: Just in case

``import { firestore } from 'firebase/app';``
throws an error, use ``import firebase from 'firebase/app';``
Then the array update function

```updateRef.update({
      products: firebase.firestore.FieldValue.arrayUnion(this.productId)
    });```

Just Incase someone else has a similar issue.

Reference

 - https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#update_elements_in_an_array

Answer (score 6):

```
import { arrayUnion } from '@angular/fire/firestore'

const path = `ai/${videoId}/panel-operation/${id}`
const myDoc: AngularFirestoreDocument<any> = this.afs.doc<any>(path)

const promise: Promise<void> = myDoc.update({ auxPanelSelections: arrayUnion({auxPanel: 'clip', operation: 'replace'}) }).catch((err: any) => {
  console.error(`oopsie - ${err.message}`)
  return null
})
```

`auxPanelSelections` is an array within the `myDoc` document

Note that the above code also works perfectly fine with `arrayRemove`

I cannot find the `@angular/fire` docs for `arrayUnion` but the generic [docs are here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#update_elements_in_an_array)