# Firestore. Add new array instead of replacing it

Tags: arrays, angular, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to store orders(quantity, price, date, etc), I want to store each one in different arrays inside an array called "orders", but when I send the data, instead of creating a new array, it overwrites the one that was already there

this is my code

**TS**

```
this.FireServices.collection("clientData").doc(uid).update({
orders: [this.dataForm.value]
})
```

The data is obtained directly from a form

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to add a new item to an array, you should [use FieldValue.arrayUnion()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59429562/how-to-use-arrayunion-with-angularfirestore) to add to the existing array.

```
this.FireServices.collection("clientData").doc(uid).update({
    orders: firestore.FieldValue.arrayUnion(this.dataForm.value)
})
```

Comment: ailoviu su moch c: